# Change of coordinate matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be a finite deminsional vector space over a field $\mathbb F$, and let $\beta=${$x_1,x_2,....x_n$} be an ordered basis for $V$. Let $Q$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matric with entries from $\mathbb F$. Define $$x'_j=\sum_{i=1}^n Q_{i,j}x_i , 1\leq j \leq n$$

and set $\beta'=${$x'_1,x'_2,....,x'_n$}. Prove that $\beta'$ is a basis for $V$ and hence that $Q$ is the change of coordinate matrix changing $\beta'$-coordinates into $\beta$-coordinates.

Since $|\beta'|=n=|\beta|$, then I only have to show linear independence to prove $\beta'$ is a basis.

I'm a little unsure about my indexing, but here is what I think is the next step:

If $$\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j x'_j=0$$
($\alpha_j \in \mathbb F$) then
$$ \alpha_1 x'_1+\alpha_2x'_2+....+\alpha_nx'_n=0$$
$$=\alpha_1\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{i,1}x_i+\alpha_2\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{i,2}x_i+...+\alpha_n\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{i,n}x_n=0$$

Then, since $Q$ is not the zero matrix since it's invertible. Also, $x_is$ are not equal to zero since they are the basis elements for $\beta$. This means $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=....=\alpha_n=0$. So $\beta'$ is linearly independent and therefore a basis for $V$.

Did I do this correctly? I feel that this is not a correct approach since I'm supposed to show that $Q$ is the change of coordinate matrix.

Any help/feedback is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Actually, for $Q$ to be a basis matrix, its entries must be vectors in $V$, unless $V=\mathbb F^n$ I think you can just say that $Q$ being invertible means the basis vectors that are its rows/columns are linearly-independent and of maximal rank, and so they are a basis for $V$.

Comment: So I wouldn't need to show that for an $v \in V$, $[v]_\beta=Q[v]_\beta'$?

Comment: @user99680 I forgot to tag you in the question above

Answer (score 1):

If we rewrite the last line $$0 = \alpha_1\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{i,1}x_i+\alpha_2\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{i,2}x_i+\cdots+\alpha_n\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{i,n}x_n,$$
as follows
$$(\sum_{j=1}^{n}Q_{1,j}a_{j})x_{1}+(\sum_{j=1}^{n}Q_{2,j}a_{j})x_{2}+\cdots+(\sum_{j=1}^{n}Q_{n,j}a_{j})x_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\sum_{j=1}^{n}Q_{i,j}a_{j})x_{i}$$
then we observe a system of linear equations. Hence, we have $Qa=0,$ where $a$ is a column vector with entries $a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots, a_{n},$ and we obtain $a = 0$ by multiplying both sides by the inverse $Q^{-1}.$ Then, $a_{1}=a_{2}\cdots=a_{n}=0$ implies $\beta^{'}$ is a linearly independent subset of $V,$ and from here, one can easily show that $\beta^{'}$ is a basis for $V.$

Subsequently, we write the coordinate vector of $x_{j}^{'}$ relative to $\beta$
$$[x_{j}^{'}]_{\beta} = [I_{V}(x_{j}^{'})]_{\beta} = [I_{V}]_{\beta^{'}}^{\beta} [x_{j}^{'}]_{\beta^{'}} = Q [x_{j}^{'}]_{\beta^{'}},$$
where $I_{V}$ is the identity transformation on $V$ and $[x_{j}^{'}]_{\beta^{'}} = e_{j},$ i.e., a $1$ in the $j$th component and 0 elsewhere. So, $Q$ changes $\beta^{'}$-coordinates into $\beta$-coordinates.